# Click() - not being executed within my foreach loop

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I was hoping if someone could help. I am trying to write a test against a search feature, which when a user enters a few characters into the search box, you are provided with suggestions matching you entered criteria. In my example below I enter the words 'cel' into the search field and I get back 3 list items. The code does not error and the foreach loop returns all three items in the list however the 'suggestion.Click()' is not being executed and I don't know why. To give some context this is for a online greeting site.

```
    <li ng-click="goSearch('Autocomplete', 'keyword')" ng-bind-html="searchForMsg()" class="ng-binding">Search for <strong>"cel"</strong></li>
    <li ng-repeat="suggestion in (suggestions = (allFacetsAutoComplete.facets | typeahead:moonpigSearchBox.term))" ng-bind-html="highlight(suggestion.DisplayName)" ng-click="selectSuggestion(suggestion)" ng-bind="suggestion.DisplayName" class="ng-binding ng-scope"><strong>cel</strong>ebration</li>
    <li ng-repeat="suggestion in (suggestions = (allFacetsAutoComplete.facets | typeahead:moonpigSearchBox.term))" ng-bind-html="highlight(suggestion.DisplayName)" ng-click="selectSuggestion(suggestion)" ng-bind="suggestion.DisplayName" class="ng-binding ng-scope">jewish <strong>cel</strong>ebrations</li>
```

---

```
    [Then(@"I select the following list item '(.*)' from my search")]
    public static void PreSelectedListOptions(string value)
    {
        var suggestedList = Driver.Instance.FindElements(By.CssSelector(".list-reset li"));
        foreach(IWebElement suggestion in suggestedList)
        {
            if(value.Equals(suggestion))
            {
                suggestion.Click();
            }
        }
    }
```

---

```
And I perform a partial search for 'cel'
And I select the following list item 'ebration' from my search
//Note: I have just copied a part of the scenario.
```

Many thanks

Comment: but your code jumps inside the if-clause? so there are suggestions that are equal to your value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Click is not executed, because you never pass condition. `value` is a string. It's not web element. You should compare web element's text with string you have:

```
if(value.Equals(suggestion.Text))
```

Also note - you pass `'ebration'` as list item value. I don't see any list items with this exact text. If you want to click each item which contains `ebration` you need to check if `suggestion.Text.Contains(value)`. Though your scenario says that you should click only one item.. Do you need foreach loop here?

Comment: Thank you very much @Sergey Berezovskiy that worked perfectly.

Comment: One thing I keep getting the following error now 'Message: Element not found in the cache - perhaps the page has changed since it was looked up'

Comment: Yes, page might be refreshed by javascript. It's common issues with Selenium testing - you can search for `StaleElementReferenceException`